# Python creating a new list that contains elements not equal to elements of the same index of two other lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a list by iterating through a two other lists using a list comprehension and only leaving integers in the list that are not equal to the same index element of the other two lists.

I have two lists with 10 integers from 0 to 10, e.g.:

```
list_1 = [0,3,2,5,7,2,3,5,9,2]

list_2 = [1,7,2,5,0,0,2,3,0,4]
```

I need a list comprehension that creates a new list of 10 integers, but each element cannot be equal to the same index element of the two lists.

An example output could be:

```
list_3 = [4,4,9,6,3,1,5,7,6,1]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So is 4 because is different than 0 and 1, is that right?

Comment: @danielMesejo Yes that is correct!

Comment: Any reason why it's 4 and not uhm, 8?

Comment: No that is completely random, as long as it's not 0 or 1

Comment: is there any range from which you choose? e.g between 1 and 10, 1 and 1000, -100 and 100?

Comment: 0 to n, n is input of the function

Comment: @user7431590 you may accept an by clicking on the tick mark beside it, the one that helped you understand the problem better. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
import random
random.seed(42)

list_1 = [0,3,2,5,7,2,3,5,9,2]
list_2 = [1,7,2,5,0,0,2,3,0,4]

n = 10
pool = set(range(n))

result = [random.sample(pool - set(t), 1)[0] for t in zip(list_1, list_2)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[3, 0, 5, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 7, 0]
```

As a faster alternative you could do:

```
result = [random.choice(list(pool - set(t))) for t in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

Comment: Genius! Thanks a lot.

Comment: There's no reason to use `random.sample` of size 1 when `random.choice` will do.

Comment: @blhsing I believe random.choice does not work with sets

Comment: @DanielMesejo Good point. A conversion to a list will do but then the advantage to `random.sample` isn't as clear-cut as I had initially thought.

Comment: @DanielMesejo Well actually I take it back. The overhead of `random.sample` with a sample size of 1 is much greater than `random.choice` with a conversion to a list: https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/XNr

Comment: @blhsing Updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

list_1 = [0,3,2,5,7,2,3,5,9,2]    
list_2 = [1,7,2,5,0,0,2,3,0,4]   
list_3 = []

for elem1 in list_1:
    for elem2 in list_2:
        x = randint(0, 9)
        if x != elem1 and x != elem2:
            list_3.append(x)
            break

print(list_3)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[6, 9, 8, 2, 6, 8, 4, 8, 0, 5]
```

EDIT:

one liner:

```
from random import randint

list_1 = [0,3,2,5,7,2,3,5,9,2]    
list_2 = [1,7,2,5,0,0,2,3,0,4]
n = 10

print([randint(0, n) for i in list_1 if i in list_2])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[2, 9, 7, 8, 5, 10, 7, 1, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def get_random(n, exclude):
    my_set = set(range(n+1))
    my_set.difference_update(set(exclude))
    return random.choice(list(my_set))

def get_random2(n, exclude):
    nums = list(range(n+1))
    while True:
        num =  random.choice(nums)
        if num not in exclude:
            return num

list1 = [0,3,2,5,7,2,3,5,9,2]
list2 = [1,7,2,5,0,0,2,3,0,4]

# print list with numbers between 0 and 10 inclusive
print([get_random(10, nums) for nums in zip(list1, list2)])
print([get_random2(10, nums) for nums in zip(list1, list2)])
```